# How can (x.y != null && ((object)x.y) == null) ever be true?

Tags: c#

I just wrote a piece of code that behaves quite differently then I would expect.
It seems to tell me that I don't know everything yet about objects, so I humbly turn myself to the wisdom of my fellow colleagues of stack overflow to point me in the right direction.

This is the code that baffles me:

```
[Test]
public void TestMySanity()
{
    var oldSet = new Identifier[0];
    var newSet = new[]
    {
        new Identifier("1"),
        new Identifier("2")
    };

    var changes = uut.TrackChanges(oldSet, newSet, x => x).ToArray();

    ChangeRecord<Identifier> xx = changes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.New != null && x.Old != null);
    if (xx != null)
    {
        if (xx.Old != null && ((object) xx.Old) == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How can something be not null and null at the same time?");
        }
        Assert.Fail("PS: this test expects a change record with Old = null and New = an Identifier");
    }
}
```

Just to be clear -> this code gets into the `Console.WriteLine(...)` which should not happen ...

Some things I have tried to get wiser:

```
Console.WriteLine("Is Object? " + (xx.Old is Object)); // = false
Console.WriteLine("Reference Equals? " + Object.ReferenceEquals(xx.Old, null)); // = true

try { Console.WriteLine(xx.Old.GetType().Name); }
catch (Exception ex)
{ Console.WriteLine("GetType() -> " + ex.Message);}
//Throws: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The remarks on this question seem to indicate that the class Identifier is important for this issue, so here it is:

```
public class Identifier : IComparable, IComparable<Identifier>, IEquatable<Identifier>
{
    //Var
    protected readonly IComparable Key;

    //Constructor
    public Identifier(IComparable key)
    {
        Key = key;
        if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
    }

    //Hashcode (Must be overridden when equals is overridden.)
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Key.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "[" + Key + "]";
    }

    //Compare
    public virtual int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return CompareTo((Identifier)obj);
    }

    public virtual int CompareTo(Identifier other)
    {
        if (other == null) return 1;
        return Key.CompareTo(other.Key);
    }

    //Equals
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals((obj as Identifier));
    }

    public virtual bool Equals(Identifier other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        return Key.Equals(other.Key);
    }

    //Can be done because a Identifier is immutable
    public static bool operator ==(Identifier A, Identifier B)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(A, null)) return false;
        return A.Equals(B);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Identifier A, Identifier B)
    {
        return !(A == B);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there's a lot of irrelevant code here, could you read and apply [mcve] please? Can you also show the `Identifier` definition, or what type you use for `T` in `ChangeRecord<T>`? Is it a struct or (nullable) value type, or does the type have an explicit conversoin operator to object?

Comment: Is `operator==` redefined for `Identifier`?

Comment: is explicit cast defined for Identifier?

Comment: I know and I intend to remove the interface and class implementation if it was not required to solve the question. Note that the interfase has `where T : class` which makes it nullable. In this case ChangeRecord<T> will be of type ChangeRecord<Identifier>

Comment: I updated the question to include the Identifier class.

Comment: Looks to me like when you cast it to object another version of the comparison operators is getting used and that is causing the issue. You should perhaps set breakpoints in your custom comparison logic and see wether it is being hit both when it checks with the identifier and when it is cast to object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the error:

```
public static bool operator ==(Identifier A, Identifier B)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(A, null)) return false;
    return A.Equals(B);
}
```

What happens if `B` is `null`? `A == B` should return `true`, sadly your comparison will `return false`;

Change it to:

```
    if (ReferenceEquals(A, null)) return ReferenceEquals(B, null);
    return A.Equals(B);
```

In general the point is that by casting to `object` like `((object) xx.Old) == null` you are forcing the C# compiler to use the `object==` operator, that simply does a `object.ReferenceEquals(A, B)`, so you bypass your buggy code.

Answer (score 2):

Little *dirty trick* with `==` and `!=` *operators* and you have it

```
public class MyX {
  public MyY y {
    get;
    set;
  }
}

public class MyY {
  public static Boolean operator == (MyY left, Object right) {
    return true;
  }

  public static Boolean operator != (MyY left, Object right) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

....

```
var x = new MyX();

if (x.y != null && (((Object) x.y) == null)) {
  Console.Write("You've got it");
}
```

So it's *possible*.

Comment: aah, it seems this will indeed be the problem. I'm gonna check those overrides to see what I did wrong. Thanks!